# Improve custom-defined variables

Tags: macros, variable

I am using the following code to define new custom variables, along with the existing ones, and use their values later in the document.

```
\newcommand\subtitle[1]{\newcommand\zzsubtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\institute[1]{\newcommand\zzinstitute{#1}}
\newcommand\fullmarks[1]{\newcommand\zzfullmarks{#1}}
%
\title{CC3 -- Mathematics}
\author{Subhajit Paul}
\institute{Salesian College, Siliguri Campus}
\date{BSc Honours 2\textsuperscript{nd} Semester Examination, 2023}
\subtitle{Real Analysis}
\fullmarks{60}
%
\makeatletter
\let\titlevalue\@title
\let\authorvalue\@author
\let\datevalue\@date
\makeatother
```

What I want now is to have a provision for an optional value for the variables. For instance, I want to write

```
\title[MATHCC3]{CC3 -- Mathematics}
```

and the value `MATHCC3` will be stored in another variable, say `\shorttitle`. However, if I write

```
\title{CC3 -- Mathematics}
```

then `\shorttitle` variable will have the same value as `\titlevalue`. The same feature should also be implemented for the custom variables like `\subtitle` and `\institute`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You should check out the xparse package (and reach new heights of bewilderment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\title}[2][\empty]{% #1 = short title (optional), #2 = title
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \def\zzshorttitle{#2}%
  \else
    \def\zzshorttitle{#1}%
  \fi
  \def\@title{#2}}
\makeatother

\title[Real Analysis]{CC3 -- Mathematics}
\author{Subhajit Paul}
%\institute{Salesian College, Siliguri Campus}
\date{BSc Honours 2\textsuperscript{nd} Semester Examination, 2023}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\zzshorttitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like this. Thanks much! A small trivia question: What is it about the `zz` part in the variable name? I checked that it works with any other name as well. So, why is this protocol? I have seen many people use the same scheme in this website. Prior apologies if this is a silly question.

Comment: You just need something to make it less likely to be a duplicate name.  LaTeX uses @ a lot (as in \@title).  Most packages use initials, like Hy for hyperref (as in \Hy@raisedlink) or LT for longtable (as in \LTchunksize).